# Is it possible to share file pointers between threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, file, sockets

We need to address some performance issues on our application. Using Visual Studio's diagnostic hub, we discovered that file operations were responsible for our issue.

We are using a file to save critical data temporarily that has to be sent via TCP/IP to a server.

The file consists of a header where information is stored, where to find a specific data set (offset and length of up to 2500 data sets in this file). The second part is the data itself, addressed by the information in the header.

When data is written to the file, first the header is read, then data is written to the next empty location, and the information in the header is updated and written again.

When data needs to be sent (in the second thread), the header is read to obtain the next offset and length of data to be read. Then the data is read and sent via TCP/IP. Until we receive the TCP/IP ACK of the server, the header is not updated again. When the ACK arrives, the header information is updated to reflect that the used dataset is now empty.

All functions involved in this process made a `fopen()` and `fclose()` to the file, which caused our performance issues.

I know that there must be some synchronization when writing the header, because when the first thread puts in new data, the second thread must obey the new write pointer in the file (if not, the newly written data will be lost).

If I am able to sync access to the file pointer, so that any time one thread is writing at a specific location, the other thread would not write too, is it safe to use the `FILE*` variable in those two threads?

Or, would it be better to have two `FILE*` variables that read and write on their own portions of the file?

I know, that I could combine both operations into one thread, but then I must address delays from synchronous socket operations.

Comment: If the data is being read/written within threads of the same process then why not just have a memory buffer and get rid of the file altogether? Or are there other reasons for using an intermediate file?

Comment: We need to save the data in case there is a network error, and if the application is closed, the data would be lost... Synchronisation of the head must take place in memory also.

Comment: You can try mmap  or IPC methods with two processes , one process generate data and the other read data and send through Tcp socket.

Comment: Messy.   It's times like this when I wonder why popular file systems do not support queue files directly:(

Comment: I mean, there has to be some easy way of avoiding the metadata write:(

Comment: It sounds like you want a database with transaction support.

Comment: I need to stay as close as possible with my current file architecture... so no Database is possible. I am thinking about memory mapped files, with which it should be possible to write single bytes at different offsets from different threads, and those files are persistent after my program is being closed... But performance?

Comment: You could also read and write directly to a block device (like a Linux LVM) bypassing filesystem overhead.  It sounds like all your operations need to be synchronous anyway,

Comment: Have you thought about what happens when your program is killed (or the machine is powered down) during a write to the file (either the data, or the header)?

Comment: @ciamej: Sabotage is always an option to destroy data. my program can handle a normal windows shut down, so this is not the problem...

Comment: @WolfgangRoth Well, lack of power is not a sabotage, but just an unfortunate occurence. Moreover, OS crash causing the entire machine to be switched off and reset is also not that rare... Also, hardware failure can simply cause the machine to switch off.

Comment: I know... right this week, I had a failure on my test equipment, and could not conduct the planned test... only 30 minutes into the test, my IPC restarted on its own, and my test did not finish until I noticed the next morning. And unfortunately I wasn't able to find the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address the performance issue, I rewrote my code, and now I am opening the file only once per thread, and do seek/read/write operations on the same file pointer. So there is no overhead on the file operations caused by repeatedly opening and closing the file.

Problem solved - at least for now.